# how to define start order in group of processes using supervisord?

Tags: supervisord

Does the program priority determine the start order? i.e. `baz` then `bar` ?

If I have:

```
[group:foo]
programs=bar,baz
```

And:

```
[program:bar]
command=/path/to/bar
priority=200
```

As well as:

```
[program:baz]
command=/path/to/baz
priority=150
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Lower priorities indicate programs that start first and shut down last at startup and when aggregate commands are used in various clients (e.g. “start all”/”stop all”). Higher priorities indicate programs that start last and shut down first.